# How to properly phrase the buttons to handover video session and asking to have the video session

Tags: buttons, language

We are building a web application that allows people to host a video session, and only one person at a time can host it.

So whoever is watching the video session, they can click a button to ask the person who is hosting the video session to take over.

And the person who is hosting the video can click a button to assign someone else to host the video session.

Being a non-native english speaker, we are not sure how to properly phrase the buttons. See image below:

1. First image : How to properly phrase "Raise your hand"? meaning I
   want to ask the person who is currently hosting the video session to
   take over the session
2. Second image : How to properly phrase "Hand over"? meaning I want to
       ask the person who is currently hosting the video session to take
       over the session

[image: How to properly phrase "Raise your hand"? meaning I want to ask the person who is currently hosting the video session to take over the session]

[image: How to properly phrase "Hand over"? meaning I want to ask the person who is currently hosting the video session to take over the session]

Comment: Not sure if this question is relevant in this forum and I am not a native english speaker myself but here goes:

**Request hosting**,

**Allow host relay**,

**Relay hosting**

Comment: "hang over" is a typo mistake in the image which should be "hand over"

Comment: Do you really want to use between 25-50% of  your screenspace for this feature? Because i dont think that it matters who's session host and who not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use <kbd>Ask to host</kbd> and <kbd>Grant video host</kbd> or shorter <kbd>Grant host</kbd>